# nested query returning values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have a table `order_details` like this

```
 id |  SKU  |  quantity_purchased | discount_price
---------------------------------------------------
1   | abc   |   1                 |     10.0
2   | abc   |   90                |     00
2   | abc   |   9                 |     00
3   | xyz   |   1                 |     50.0
3   | xyz   |   2                 |     50.0
4   | xyz   |   100               |     00
4   | xyz   |   100               |     00
-----------------------------------------------
```

My query is

```
select 
(select sum(quantity_purchased)  from order_details where discount_price > 0.00) as qty_discount,
(select sum(quantity_purchased)  from order_details where discount_price = 0.00)as qty_original,
sku
from order_details
GROUP BY sku
```

my required result is

```
  SKU   |  quantity_original | quantity_discount
---------------------------------------------------
 abc    |   1                 |     99
 xyz    |   3                 |     200
-----------------------------------------------
```

that is, I need two columns for same `sku` after calculation,

I am unable to establish the logic, I have tried using `GROUP BY` in nested query, but it doesn't work...
any help is highly appreciated..
thanks

UPDATE:
trying to do via this but still a failure,

```
select 
(select sum(quantity_purchased)  from order_details where discount_price > 0.00 ) as qty_discount,
(select sum(quantity_purchased)  from order_details where discount_price = 0.00 )as qty_original,
sku
from order_details
where sku = (select distinct sku from order_details)
GROUP BY sku
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation` for this:

```
select sku, 
       sum(case when discount_price != 0 then quantity_purchased 
                else 0 
           end) quantity_original,
       sum(case when discount_price = 0 then quantity_purchased 
                else 0 
           end) quantity_discount
from order_details
group by sku
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5fe597/1)

---

```
Results:

| SKU | quantity_original | quantity_discount |
|-----|-------------------|-------------------|
| abc |                 1 |                99 |
| xyz |                 3 |               200 |
```

Comment: +1, awesome....thanks a million, you made my day boss...one thing, seems like you have interchanged the column names (original has become discount) but that is not the problem, have got your logic, thanks a billion...you really helped a lot...